# Fastest way to split a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, asp.net-web-api

I have a byte array is in string with delimiter as ',' (comma).
EX. {0,0,222,1,22}
But the problem is that the string of a huge length.
Like 5 MB - 6 MB of text file.
I have a code that give me a proper byte array like

```
[0] 0
[1] 0 
[2] 222
[3] 1
[4] 22
```

But this requires 5-6 minutes.

```
    var videoParameter = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["videoParameter"];
    var getContent = videoParameter.Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
```

Please suggest me fastest way to split a string in c#.

OR 
Suggest me in which format should mobile team send video file to web api
but I don't want to store file to server side.
The scenario is mobile team sending a byte array request to web api.

Comment: How long does it take to convert the string to a char array? That may be a way to go.

Comment: Char array will give me byte values ?

Comment: No? Your question asks about splitting a string, and you use var in your example. I would suggest splitting the string object and potentially utilizing separate threads to manually construct new strings yourself.

Comment: What's the encoding used?

Comment: `var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string)` maybe is what you're looking for?

Comment: I just want to mention that using Split on a large input is considered an expensive operation. Because you are doubling memory consumption by using it - each Split call would allocate new string objects. And each allocation would require to copy content into newly allocated strings.

Comment: @Mikael for encoding at JS side use the concept of Uint8Array.

Comment: @lerthe61 then the new C# ranges (I tried to find the specific type and I think it's range)?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I think that [Span<T>](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md) can be handy in this situation

Comment: @lerthe61 yes, it was Span I was looking for (not Range).

Answer (score 1):

Use the type `IFormFile` to receive a binary file on the web server and then read it using a `StreamReader` that way you wont need to parse from `string` to `byte`. You can also use parallel logic to read a binary stream however, this might not be as useful as your requirements may require you to read the file in order.

Comment: I don't want to send a file I will receive from mobile team.I think the IFormFile is not present at mobile team they are sending a byte array to my api thats why IFormFile will not work..

Comment: Yes it will. IFormFile is an interface that will accept a binary stream from a form given from a HTTP request. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2